# Convert raw data from hexadecimal (16) to text

Tags: encoding, hex, converters, tcpdump, payload

I did a tcpdump and I have the data payload in 16 hexadecimal. I want to convert the payload to plain text, how do I do that?

I have tried reading about encoding but I don't think that is going to help.

Thank you!

Comment: did you try a third party service like http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/hexadecimal/ ?

Comment: I did. I ended up building my own program